# Character is not implemented correctly in Assembly ArmV8

Tags: c, assembly, armv8

I am using armv8 assembly to write a program. The problem occurs at the point where I try to scan a character from the keyboard. I have two input calls. The first scans an integer and the second scans a character. When I scan a number bigger than 255, the character is not read correctly as I can understand. I am scanning using the following commands:

```
.first:
    .string "%d"
.second:
    .string " %c"
 main:
.LFB0:

    add     x1, x29, 28
    adrp    x0, .LC1
    add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC1
    bl      scanf                //Scanning the first integer number from keyboard
    ldr     w20, [x29, 28]

    add     x1,x29,28
    adrp    x0, .LCC
    add     x0,x0, :lo12:.LCC
    bl      scanf                                   //Scans the character from keyboard
    ldr     w1, [X29, 28]                           //Loads the character inside x21
```

The purpose of the program is to get an integer and a character and make some calculations. So I am comparing the character and I am jumping into the labels needed. However, when the number is greater than 255 then the character is not read correctly and does not jump to the correct label. When I use "%s" instead of " %c", the program works just fine.

Comment: So apparently (and most likely) the `char` type is 8 bits in size which can't hold input larger than 255 (or between -127 and 128 if it is a `signed` type) - what did you expect to happen in that case?

Comment: Yes but am not storing the integer inside the character register. The integer it is stored in w20 and character in w1. I don't know what is causing the problem since the character register and integer register are separated.

Comment: Used debugger to check values in regs? I didn't do ARM asm for long time, so I'm a bit rusty, but generally it looks like you use the same buffer memory to store result of `scanf` (memory at x29+28). But then in both cases you load word from there, while the `%c` reads only 8 bit character, so I think the `w1` contains your character in low 8 bits, and garbage (copy of integer upper bits) in upper 24 bits. use for example `and w1,w1,#255`  to clear upper bits, or byte load instead of `ldr`, if ARM has one (not sure now + don't want to google).

Comment: Looks like most of the arm assemblers have also `ldrb` pseudo instruction, so you can use that one to fetch the char `ldrb w1, [X29, 28]`, if it will compile. Mind you, even your current version very likely has the correct value in low 8 bits of w1, so you can look at this problem also from other side, this part being correct, but later working with the char value in wrong way, as with word, instead of byte. But zero-extending byte value is usually less error-prone, than fixing all compares/etc later to byte size.

Comment: The ldrb w1, [x29,28] did the trick thank you!!!